# PyLint evaluation Configuration

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

What do the various variables in the PyLint `evaluation` configuration setting (`error`, `warning`, `refactor`, `convention`, `statement`) represent? Are there any other variables available in the calculation?

Answer (score 2):

As pylint --help say:

--evaluation=
 Python expression which should return a note less than                         10 (10 is the highest note). You have access to the                         variables errors warning, statement which respectively                         contain the number of errors / warnings messages and                         the total number of statements analyzed. This is used                         by the global evaluation report (RP0004). [current:                         10.0 - ((float(5 * error + warning + refactor +                         convention) / statement) * 10)]

Comment: Are `refactor` and `convention` also counters counting the occurrences of refactoring and convention rule-set triggers?

Comment: Try to find such lines in report. They are values for formula.  
641 statements analysed.  

Messages by category  
+-----------+-------+---------+-----------+  
|type       |number |previous |difference |  
+===========+=======+=========+===========+  
|convention |186    |...  
+-----------+-------+---------+-----------+  
|refactor   |2      |...  
+-----------+-------+---------+-----------+  
|warning    |18     |...  
+-----------+-------+---------+-----------+  
|error      |1      |...